# Haystack searching multiple fields

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am currently building a page in django, where there are 4 form fields, 2 text, 2 select fields, and when submitted it takes those fields and searches several models for matchinng items.

the model looks like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="the user associated with this profile")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Birthdate (yyyy-mm-dd)")
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (u'M', u'Male'),
        (u'F', u'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = GENDER_CHOICES, default = 'M')
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile', blank=True, null=True)
    nationality = CountryField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    command_cert = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="COMMAND certification")
    experience = models.ManyToManyField('userProfile.MartialArt', blank=True, null=True)
```

and I am trying to search the first_name field, the last_name field, the nationality field, and the experience field, but say if the first_name field is blank, I need to pass an empty value so it returns all rows, then filter from there with last name the same way, for some reason it is not working at all for me. this is my sqs:

```
results = SearchQuerySet().models(Person).filter(first_name=sname, last_name=slastname, nationality=scountry, experience__pk=sexperience)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing specific errors or a stack trace, it's hard to determine what "is not working at all".

Edit: Looking at your provided view code, I would remove the filter and return all of the objects for your Fighter, Referee, Insider, and Judge models. This is to ensure that the issue here lies in the filter, and not something else.

Then, once I'd verified that objects are being placed into results, I'd put in the filters one at a time to determine what the problematic filter is. Give this a try and reply back with your results.

Comment: no matter what combination of entries I use in the field, even when they're all blank it returns nothing.

Comment: Can you paste the entire view for this page? There are a multitude of reasons why your filter wouldn't return anything, but I can't begin to troubleshoot it without more information.

Comment: This smells like a search indexes problem.  Can we see what search_indexes.py looks like?  What does `results = SearchQuerySet().models(Person).filter(content=sname)` return?  (only works if `Document=True` is set for a given search field).

Comment: Yeah, this is my entire search_indexes: `import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()`

Comment: however, if I remove the filter's from that Query it returns all of the items in the database of the models I specify

Comment: As you added more arguments to the filter, which one caused the filter to return an empty QuerySet?